# How to change the shape of the object so that it doesn't change in all keys in the animation?

Tags: animation

I'm making animation and I need to pull a cylinder in the direction X there and when I go to edit mode and stretch the cylinder, it caused changing the object in all keyframes but I do not need this I want to change this object were only in one keyframe.

Comment: Can you give an example because I didn't understand you very well?

Comment: Create a keyframe (*Location, Rotation and Scale*) at frame 1, move your player at the frame you want, move your cylinder, scale it on Z, create a new keyframe (*Location, Rotation and Scale*), the object will progressively stretch on Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyframes you're placing are **object** location, rotation, and scale keyframes. Your edit is an **object data** edit. To store **object data** edits in a way that can be keyframed, you need to use *Shape keys*. You store your edit in a shape key, and animate its *Value* from 0.0 to 1.0.

[image: Shape Key]

For your specific case, this may be an overkill as your edit can be done at the **object** level.

There is another easier way to keyframe object data edits by using an add-on that comes bundled with Blender (if I remember correctly) called **AnimAll**.

[image: AnimAll]

Geometry nodes should also allow you to edit the object data in a way that can be keyframed.

Comment: Yes it works, but when I change the value of the object of the second frame using shape keys, these changes are also applied to the first frame

Comment: Are you sure you're placing a keyframe on the value of the shape key? It should light up in yellow if you do as shown in my screenshot. On the first keyframe, the value should be 0.0, and on the second, it should be 1.0.

Comment: Aaahhh I've just done something wrong, thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the keyframe interpolation to constant. Or you can duplicate the previous keyframe and place it at the frame before you want to see the change.